# Matching pans with a fitting lid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, relations

There are $m$ lids, and $n$ pans. How many possible relations, that describe which lid fits which pan, are there? (We only look at relations, where every pan has at least one fitting lid)

There are $4$ scenarios:

(a) both the lids and pans are distinguishable

(b) only the lids are distinguishable

(c) only the pans are distinguishable

(d) both are indistinguishable

Example:
There are $3$ pans and $3$ lids.

Relation $1$: lid $1$ fits pan $1$ and pan $2$, lid $2$ fits pan $3$

Relation $2$: lid $1$ fits pan $1$, lid $2$ fits pan $3$, lid $3$ fits pan $2$

.
.
.
etc.

I am not sure whether a relation like "lid $1$ fits pan $1$ and pan $2$, lid $2$ fits pan $2$ (**and not pan $1$**), lid $3$ fits pan $3$" is allowed, but would most likely assume, that it is not allowed.